# CSS inline text, random line paddings/gutters

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to do something a bit different with subheaders whereby the text looks a bit messy. I don't want to change the markup to have `<br/>`s and other elements.

I want to know if anyone has a neat idea of how this might be done **purely in css**. Have a look at the image:

[image]

So in this example we have sort of... odd gutters & margins on both left and right.

I'm wondering about if this is even possible. Again, I'd rather not change a straightforward markup ie.:

```
<h2>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</h2>
```

Comment: Why? If this is the layout you want to achieve, why not put in some straightforward `<br>`s?

Comment: it would create annoyances for RSS and future redesign.. it's just a bit messy in terms of code... hygiene? if thats a term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the original markup, I got as far as this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QT9v8/2/)

```
h2 {
 width:10em; text-indent:-2em; margin-left:1em;
}
h2:before {
 display:block; content:''; float:left; width:1em; height:2em;
}
```

Comment: that's a beauty, I'm genuinely awestruck. Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p
{
white-space:pre;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
The quick brown fox 
   jumps over the  
 lazy dog
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ohhh, I like it..... no extra tags and it won't have consequences for RSS and future proofing, it's just a case of adding randomized whitespace!!!.... points!!

Comment: seriously, loving that, I wouldn't have thought of that if I was fiddling all day... This is why Stackoverflow is sooo useful... I'm going to keep the question open for a few hour in case any other genius has another suggestion but otherwise I'm going for this!

Comment: @Alex, Even I have felt the same, I ask them some query within few minutes someone will come up with one answer and after 10 minutes , i will get a better answer more than what I asked for.

Comment: I think your point was just proved below. I'm going for that answer simply because it is closer to the brief of not changing things also white-space:pre is not working on ie8.. which sadly is still a consideration these days whereas the css option by Mr Lister seems to be fine in ie8

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your markup, this isn't possible with plain CSS

Comment: hmm, was hoping that wasn't the case, thought someone might have an idea with psuedo elements negative margins on first letters etc etc..

Comment: I can but was hoping not to, I know I could do some javascript post-load as well as some php to chunk the flow up but that would be my second favourite option